# Compare PHP arrays for same Value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have an array called parts and contains 7000 items. I have another array that called images and contains 34000 items. What I'm trying to do is get the part number from array 1 and look in the images array to see if there is a match. If a match is found then insert the image path and part id to a table. Here is an example:

This one item of the parts array

```
array:8 [▼
  "id" => 1
  "rank" => 0
  "product_category_id" => "5"
  "name" => "BRACKETS, METAL"
  "part_num" => "100G"
  "description" => "Gold Line aluminum bracket back mounting"
  "created_at" => "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
  "updated_at" => "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
]
```

Images array

```
array:7 [▼
  0 => "100G_3Q_H.jpg"
  1 => "13VX_3Q_L.jpg"
  2 => "2025_TS_1.jpg"
]
```

So as you can see I'm trying to see if part_num 100G matches the image name in the images array. if it does get the image name and the part id from the parts array.

Any help is much appreciated.

> BTW I'm using Laravel 5.2

Thanks

Comment: The format of the image filenames does not appear to be consistent. Are there specific rules for how the part number will be included in the filenames? Will it always be at the beginning? Will it be the entire term before the first `_` or `-`?

Comment: Yes. the part number is at the beginning of the filename after that there is an underscore. Every image name follows this pattern

Comment: Ok. I was specifically asking because of `2025TS-1.jpg` in your example.

Comment: Sorry about that. I forgot to add an underscore I just updated my post. Thanks

Comment: No worries; just wanted to make sure. Two more questions: is this a one-time operation? And is it possible for there to be more than one image that matches a part number?

Comment: Yes it's only a one time operations because I don't want to manually insert 34000 images in a database table. Yes there are some parts that has more than one image

Comment: It sounds like you will need to ensure that the images are sorted alphanumerically and once you know for certain they are sorted you can index the image array for a match and do your insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create an array of all part numbers.

Then loop through the images, split out the part number and check if it exists in the part numbers array.

If it does then add it to an array of images for that part number.

You can then either filter out the empty  part number arrays or discard them when adding the images to the database.

```
foreach ($parts as $part) {
  $imageMatches[$part['part_num']] = [];
}

foreach ($partImages as $image) {
  $imageParts = explode('_', $image);
  $imageNum = $imageParts[0];

  if (array_key_exists($imageNum, $imageMatches)) {
    array_push($imageMatches[$imageNum], $image);
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much guys for your help.

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help

Answer (score 1):

Because the image file names are of a consistent format, you can preprocess your images array to map part numbers to corresponding file names.

```
foreach ($images as $filename) {
    $partnum = strtok($filename, '_');
    $map[$partnum][] = $filename; 
}
```

This will create an array with part numbers as keys and arrays of filenames as values.

This way, it will be much more efficient to find matching values when you iterate your parts array.

```
foreach ($parts as $part) {
    if (isset($map[$part['part_num']]) {
        $images_array = $map[$part['part_num']];
        // insert whichever of the images you want
    }
}
```